# How to fetch module value in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

How to fetch the value of module in ejabberd.I mean the current module in which my control is.Secondly will it be fetched in string or binary.Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module_value=?MODULE.Will give value in string.You can use list_to_binary() function to convert it into binary